# Metamask SDK being not able to detect 'accountsChanged` event

Tags: ethereum, metamask, evm

I am trying to migrate my metamask wallet connect code from using `window.etherum` to metamask SDK for future potential mobile users.
And I am running into a major issue that seems like the `accountsChanged` event cannot be listened by `metamask.on`.

The following example nextjs code is able to replicate this issue.

```js
"use client";
import { MetaMaskSDK } from "@metamask/sdk";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [metamask, setMetamask] = useState<MetaMaskSDK | void>(undefined);

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          getWalletFromWindow().then(setMetamask);
        }}
      >
        getSDK
      </div>
      {metamask ? (
        <div
          onClick={() =>
            metamask.connect().then((accounts) => {
              console.log("Connected, accounts:", accounts);
            })
          }
        >
          Connect
        </div>
      ) : null}

      {metamask ? (
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(metamask);

            metamask.on("accountsChanged", (a) =>
              console.log("Account Changed ", a)
            );
          }}
        >
          Add change event
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </main>
  );
}

const getWalletFromWindow = async (): Promise<MetaMaskSDK | void> => {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    throw new Error("Cannot get Metamask without a window");
  }
  const MMSDK = new MetaMaskSDK({
    dappMetadata: {
      name: "Example Node.js Dapp",
      url: window.location.href,
    },
    // Other options
  });
  const metamask = await MMSDK.init();
  if (metamask)
    metamask.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) =>
      console.log("accounts changed listened by metamask.on", accounts)
    );
  // @ts-ignore
  window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) =>
    console.log("accounts changed listened by window.ethereum.on", accounts)
  );
  return metamask;
};
```

In the runtime of above code, the `accountsChanged` event can be detected by the `window.ethereum.on` listener but not SDK object `metamask.on` listener. See the video [herewith](https://github.com/notifi-network/notifi-sdk-ts/assets/127958634/bfafd025-e504-4cf9-89cb-e602961f5324).

Appreciate if any hint could be given.